# Emacs: set-frame-height doesn't work when I create a new frame

Tags: emacs, customization, frame

In my .emacs initialisation file, I have a command called `(set-frame-height (selected frame) 55)` which resizes the frame height so it takes up most of my vertical screen space. I have this command placed at the end of the .emacs file to make sure it works.

I like to make multiples copies of the frame so that I can work on different sections of the same piece of code simultaneously. The problem is that when I create a new frame using `C-x 5 2` then the new frame doesn't take on the frame size I want. Instead it goes back to the default frame size. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For new frames you can setup parameters in `default-frame-alist` variable, for example, following way:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 48))
```

I have following code in my config:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Consolas-13"))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 48))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 145))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "grey92"))
(setq initial-frame-alist default-frame-alist)
(setq special-display-frame-alist default-frame-alist)
```

to setup parameters for all frames...

Answer (score 4):

Try [after-make-frames-functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Frames.html) and this sort of thing:

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
          '(lambda (f)
         (with-selected-frame f
       ;set frame height
)))
```